# Why is an attribute option "missing"?

Tags: magento2, dropdown-attribute

When creating a new dropdown attribute:

Magento claims that the attribute option is missing.  But what's missing?

[image: Attribute option is "missing"!]

Comment: Looks like bug. If you can reproduce it on clean installation please create issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a confirmed bug in 2.0.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2876

Here is another workaround:  Add a new value to the options and delete it again.  You will then be able to submit the form.